# Problem with Nodemon(Failed at the nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall script) / problem with npm

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I have messed it up with the commands while installing `nodejs` then re-installed `nodejs` but when I run install nodemon I get the following error:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN restfullnodejs@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN restfullnodejs@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! file C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall: `node bin/postinstall || exit 0`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs\git\bin\bash.exe ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-01T11_06_31_892Z-debug.log
```

I have tried `npm config set script-shell "C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs\git\bin\bash.exe"` , `npm cache clean --force` but all in vain. I wonder where I went wrong.

I'm totally new to NodeJS

Comment: the line `wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})` may be a clue. I'm guessing you are using `git-bash` ?

Comment: how do i resolve this issue?